Excel add-in "is not a valid Office add-in" and command prompt is "unable to locate input assembly"
I've finished designing an add-in for Excel in Visual Studio and am getting this message from Excel once I select the file and try to add it (when I go file>options>Add-ins>Manage: COM Add-ins (drop-down menu)>Go>Add>[select my file]:
"[File path \ .. \ ..\file] is not a valid Office add-in."
Additionally, when I try to use regasm to register my add-in (I checked and my computer has RegAsm.exe; I plugged in "Regasm [file path\file]) on my computer using the command prompt as an administrator), the response I got was that it is "unable to locate input assembly '[File path \ .. \ ..\file]' or one of its dependencies." I also tried "regasm [file path\file] /codebase" and that gave the same message.
Oddly enough, I also could not find the add-in file location unless I copied it from Visual Studio. Once opened, I copied the file folders (...source\repo\bin\debug) into another location that I could find.
I tried all the things that ChatGPT suggested (so please plug this question into ChatGPT before you give a suggestion) and none worked (e.g. add-in version and bit size is compatible (add-in = version 15, Office = version 16) with my computer and Excel version, checked permissions).
